# Building custom ios control based on elements of native controls

Tags: ios

I would like to create range slider control (slider with two handles, one for lower bound, one for upper bound). Is there a way to extract from UITextView control text selection handles, to make my range slider look the same as text selection? I would like to use at least the same graphics/layout without hard copying it to my project.

Comment: Maybe add more details about what you're trying to "select", would help give you a better suggestions.

Comment: @bensarz: I need range slider to filter UITableView with strings that are in some specific order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create a subclass of `UIControl` and implement everything there. You should find good articles on how `UIControl` subclasses are working.

Then you implement two `UIView`s, one for the left, one for the right button. You need to do the tracking (of movement) completely yourself, but this is pretty straight forward.

To achieve the look of the text selection control, you can use [iOS-Artwork-Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/iOS-Artwork-Extractor) to get your hands on the systems assets, but I highly recommend not steeling Apples property to then submit it back to them ;-)

[You can simply follow this tutorial (OMG, look at their example)](http://www.raywenderlich.com/36288/how-to-make-a-custom-control)

**EDIT** *appendix*

Me and [@JanGreve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/363777/jan-greve) agreed on strongly discouraging from using the `UITextView` selection controls (in terms of assets) for another reason: People are familiar with these controls being used for a specific functionality.

If you provide different UX, as you clearly want to, please use different knobs. The ones of `UISlider` would be more suitable.

Comment: The tutorial link's description made my day. I'll leave my answer around because it does have a valid point not incorporated here.

Answer (score 2):

No. Also, that would not be advisable, because different kinds of data should have different UI Elements representing that. Text selection is not a slider for a range as such. At least, from an UX perspective.

Comment: ... A better way would probably be to stay close to the original `UISlider`.

Comment: Actually theres no reason for discouraging the creation of custom controls. If the UI requires it, it should be acceptable. For example selecting a range of frequency going out from an audio filter...

Comment: Don't get me wrong, you are completly right. What I discourage is using the look and feel of some existing UI for other data in the creation process, as that tends to lead to confusion. Not the general idea of creating custom controls.

Comment: Okay, got you. Then I concur!

Comment: @JanGreve: I cannot use original UISlider because I am required to presents some additional information (ranges) with colours: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5nplp5mxw1s7fme/range%20slider-or-seekbar.png?dl=1 . I would not like to cover those colours with slider's handle, so approach with text selection seemed to be solution, but you have a point, that this could mess UI.

Comment: ... Like I said: stay close to, not make due with what apple provides you with :-)

Comment: @mkk: to intercept here again ;) Read the tutorial. You should be able to draw one layer each color at the right position. Then simply keep the controls height bigger than the "drawer" line and position your control knobs below. Three views, one wrapper view, some custom drawing code.